# Move one folder from one place to another one

Tags: java

I am trying to move one folder from c:\root to a different place, let's say, directly to the project folder by using the code below. The variable `newFolder` is declared as class variable and it has been used in another method where user can rename folder to a different name and it holds the name of the folder that I want to move. The variable `fileManager` is for a new folder where I want to move my folder. When I run this code I always get `"Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is not moved."`. So for some reason it skips `if` condition and goes to `else` without moving the folder where I want. Can some one show me how to modify my code in order to move one folder from one place to another one?

```
File fileManager = new File(newFolder.getName());
try{                
    if(fileManager.renameTo(new File(fileManager.getName()))){
        System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is moved.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is not moved.");
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error - Folder not found!");
}
```

Comment: to be honest, I doubt it is skipping the condition. It is more likely that the result of the condition is simply false. If you want to be sure, store the value of the condition in a boolean variable, and output that at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `renameTo()` on the **existing** file.

Your code currently is trying to rename the new folder (fileManager) to something, but the new folder (probably) does not exist on your filesystem so it returns false because there is nothing to rename.

Actually, I can't see anything that looks like the original file handle anywhere in this code, but you are going to need the original file in order to rename it.

Your code actually does nothing since it just renames a file to itself:

`fileManager.renameTo(new File(fileManager.getName())`

I am not sure whether this would return true or false if the file exists already on the OS. Does it count as a "successful rename" if you rename a file to itself?

You probably want something that looks more like this (guessing variable names):

`oldFileOrFolder.renameTo(fileManager)`

I also got rid of the new File constructor since your object already is of type File.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Files.move method instead, I had no issues with it. Below is an example using a file instead of a folder.

```
static File fileManager = new File("C:\\template.xls");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path originalPath = Paths.get(fileManager.getPath());
        Path newPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\template.xls");

        if(Files.move(originalPath, newPath , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING) != null){
            System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is moved.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is not moved.");
        }

 }
```

As suggested by gnomed, you can also fix your issue with the renameTo method by calling it on the original folder/file, which in this case might be 'newFolder' (confusing name) since it looks to be an actual reference to a file. Below is code with the revision.

```
static File newFolder = new File("C:\\template.xls");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File fileManager = new File(newFolder.getName());
    try{                
        if(newFolder.renameTo(fileManager)){
            System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is moved.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Folder " + fileManager.getName() + " is not moved.");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error - Folder not found!");
    }
}
```